# Слово слово или слово "слово"

Tags: пунктуация

> В русском языке есть слово мир, слово дом, а еще слово слово.
>   В русском языке есть слово "мир", слово "дом", а еще слово "слово".

Как правильно?

Comment: По-моему, правильно с кавычками, но я не уверен, каким правилом это диктуется.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Правильно с кавычками:

> В русском языке есть слово "мир", слово "дом", а еще слово "слово".

Кавычки используются [при переводе значения иноязычного слова, при описании значения слова, и т. п.](http://russkiyyazik.ru/370/).

Comment: Можно, пожалуйста, источник?

Answer (score -2):

[правило](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=170#pp170): кавычками выделяются слова, употребленные не в своем обычном значении,  или на которые надо обратить внимание.

В вашем предложении «дом» и «мир» точно употреблены не в своем значении, насчет «слова» пусть разбираются специалисты по рекурсии, но внимание на него обратить надо. 
Поэтому кавычки нужны.

В крайнем случае, например, если кавычек получается слишком много, можно использовать шрифт: «слово **слово**». 
Но совсем никак не выделять, конечно, нельзя.